# How can the user clear the data from shared storage folder in UWP?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

I was creating a UWP app.
And I wanted to use the "shared storage folder"
Where my requirements were simple as follows:

1) The user stores sensitive data (could be large files photos,videos,etc)
in the app.

2) There are times when an app crashes on start and hence the user has to reinstall the app during which the user loses all of his sensitive data stored in the app.

3) In order to overcome 2) I want to create a helper app which in case when the main app starts crashing the user can install it and with the help of "shared storage folder" can recover the sensitive data.

But as I was reading [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.getpublishercachefolder.aspx) doc on shared storage folder, it states that

> Data in the shared storage folder is not backed up or roamed. Also,
>   the user can clear the contents of the shared storage folder.

I don't mind the backing up part, but how can a normal user just clear the contents of the shared storage folder?

Does that mean I cannot use the shared storage based on my requirements?

Comment: I think that it refers that the user can clear shared folder uninstalling the app or the apps of the same publisher.
Citing from documentation:
"_The shared storage folder is automatically cleaned up when the last app from the publisher is uninstalled_."

Comment: So I need not worry in this case. Also do you know if there is any limit to the folder?

Comment: As far as I know, no, it should work just like a normal local folder.